# Loop a function using the previous output as input

Tags: python, loops

When my function foo generating a new element, I want to reuse the output and put it in foo n-times. How can I do it?

My function:

```
def foo(x):
    return x + 3


print(foo(1))
>>>4
```

For now. I'm using this method:

```
print(foo(foo(foo(1))))
```

Comment: What you are searching for is called recursion

Comment: Actually what he's searching for is called a loop.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways to do what you want. First is `recursion`, but this involves changing `foo()` a bit, like so:

```
def foo(x, depth):
    if depth <= 0:
        return x
    return foo(x+3, depth-1)
```

and you'd call it like `foo(1, n)`

The other way is with a loop and temp variable, like so

```
val = 1
for _ in range(0, n):
    val = foo(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop for this:

```
value = 1
for i in range(10):
    value = foo(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are searching for is called recursion:

```py
def foo(x, n=1):
    if n == 0:
        return x
    return foo(x + 3, n - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo(x,y):
    for i in range(y):
        x = x + 3
    return x

print (foo(10,3))
```

Output:

```
19
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible with lambda and reduce

[Reduce function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reduce-in-python/)

```
from functools import reduce

def foo(x):
    return x + 3

print(reduce(lambda y, _: foo(y), range(3), 1))
```

You will get 10 as result

```
# y = assigned return value of foo.
# _ = is the list of numbers from range(3) for reduce to work
# 3 = n times
# 1 = param for x in foo
```